# Are coloured numbers damage breakdown or additional damage?

Tags: atelier-rorona-plus

I got Rorona a Staff that deals all elemental damage so when she attacks there's the white number and a bunch of coloured numbers for the various elements. ie

- Blue = Water
- Red = Fire
- Yellow = Eletricity
- Brown = Earth

however if the white number says -200 and then the various elemental number say -25, are the elemental numbers apart of the 200 or is it ontop of it? so

- -100 Non Element + -25 Fire + -25 Water + -25 Eletricity + -25 Earth = -200 Total (Displayed)

VS

- -200 Non Element (Displayed) + -25 Fire + -25 Water + -25 Eletricity + -25 Earth = -300 Total